# Inserting navigation path in many files

Tags: navigation, editing

I am building a website with a few hundred songs. I made a file for each song, and I inserted a navigation bar with dropdown menus at the top of every file. The menus classify the songs in various ways. So every page is easily reachable from every page.

But now I have decided that each page should also contain a line at the top, under the navigation bar, that shows the location of that song in the classification menus. So for example if I choose a song classified under "1965" from the dropdown menu and open that page, there should be a line that indicates that the song is in the 1965 collection.

What is the best way to do this now that I have already created over 600 files for the various songs? My idea is to add some code describing the directory path to each of the files but I would like to find a way to automate that without having to open and edit 600+ files. All the files are in the same directory.

To be specific, all the files contain this code, where the only variable string (that changes from file to file) is enclosed in brackets, [Title1].

```
<?php include 'menu.php'; ?> 
</div>
<br>
<center>
<br>
<table align=center width=1150>
<tr>
<th align=justify> 
<FONT SIZE=4> [Title1] </FONT><br>
```

I would like to insert some code after the third line like this:

```
<?php include 'menu.php'; ?> 
</div> 
<br> 
<div id="navbar" > 
&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="RecSongs_page.php">Recorded Songs</a>  -> 
<a href="[1952_page.php]">[1952]</a> -> [Title1] </div> 
<center> 
<br> 
<table align=center width=1150>
<tr> 
<th align=justify> 
<FONT SIZE=4> [Title1] </FONT><br>
```

where again the only variable strings in the inserted code are enclosed in brackets, [1952_page.php],  [1952], and [Title1]. The information for [1952_page.php] and [1952] comes from the filename 1952.php of another, unique file (in the same directory) that contains code where [Title1] appears (there will be no other files containing Title1 in their code), and [Title1] is obtained from the last line of the existing code.

My programming experience is between zero and negligible, and I realize now that creating 600+ files was a bad idea, but I wonder if some kind soul can now get me unstuck from being between the rock of having to open and edit 600+ files and the hard place of having to re-write the entire site from scratch...

Comment: I think you should look into databases and what they are used for.  You shouldn't be creating a file per song for the very reason you've found out (repeated code)

Comment: Yes you are right. I wonder if there is a way out of it now short of starting everything from scratch.